# "We would have more to gain + stop doing that in this way"

Tags: sentence-construction, conditional-constructions

Is this sentence correct?

> We would have ***more to gain by stopping to approach*** people like that

If not, what about these:

> We would have ***more to gain if we would stop approaching*** people like this
>
> We would ***gain more if we don't approach*** people like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *We would have more to gain by stopping to approach people like that

Is not standard.

> ?We would have more to gain by stopping approaching people like that.

Would, I think, be grammatically unacceptable to most experts/experienced English users. At best it would be awkward to the native speaker's eye, if not ear. I would expect to hear this kind of construction in ordinary speech sometimes, but not to read it in print.

> We would have more to gain if we would stop approaching people like this.

Is ok, but the following sounds more natural:

> We would have more to gain if we stopped approaching people like this.

or

> We would (we'd) have more to gain if we stop approaching people like this.

As a matter of style, I'd generally prefer to refine it to:

> We will (we'll) gain more if we stop approaching people like this.

or

> We would (we'd) gain more if we stop (or stopped) approaching people like this.

Comment: Thanks for your propositions! How would it sound using "would" for the last one: "we would gain more if we stop  approaching people like this"?

Comment: Thanks for your edit! "Some of us have discussed this issue recently" sorry, I don't understand, what issue are you talking about? (Could you give a link?)

Comment: One of the issues is the verb form when we talk about something that is "unreal", for example, a possibility, an "if". This is mentioned here http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/77554/using-the-past-tense-to-describe-unreal-hypothetical-or-impossible-situations.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid both your sentences are slightly incorrect. Try these :

> "We would have more to gain by **not** approaching people like that"

and

> "We would have more to gain if we stop approaching people like this"

Comment: Thanks! The last one sound weird, but I'm not a native.

Comment: don't remove it, you are definitely *more* native than me! Let's wait for some confirmations.

Comment: @JimReynolds, I'm sorry. That was an obvious mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I would definitely use *stopped* not *stop* here.

Comment: I concur with @Araucaria: the irrealis *would* in the consequence clause calls for an irrealis past form in the condition clause.